# Why my class based view is not authenticating my user?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-decorators

I am using rest_framework_simplejwt for authentication. My user/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views as user_views
from user.security.jwt_auth import GetToken
admin.autodiscover()


# Setup the URLs and include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', GetToken.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

This route works well and it returns the access_token and the refresh_token.
Now this is my client/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from client import views as client_views
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = [
    path('client', client_views.ClientList.as_view()),
    path('client/<int:pk>', client_views.ClientDetail.as_view()),
    path('create_client', client_views.create_client)
]
```

Here I am trying to use a decorator for the class. The decorator works well, the problem is that inside the decorator function the request.user does not exist, instead I have to do request.request.user. And when I do that the user is AnonymousUser. I already tried this decorator on the function based view by sending the access_token in the Authorization header and I am able to get the correct user, in other words the JWT Auth works automatically. Then Why it is not working in this scenario?

user/security/decorators.py

```
def authentication_for_class(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # todo: Finish permissions
        print(request.request.user)
        if request.request.user.is_anonymous:
            return JsonResponse({"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."}, status=403)
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

And this is my client/view.py

```
from user.security.decorators import authentication_for_class


class ClientList(APIView):

    @authentication_for_class
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ClientList, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```